# Can I install TFS 2010 using SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

Can I install TFS 2010 on top of a SQL Server 2012 RC0 installation?  I do not need the sharepoint integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that TFS 2010 does NOT support SQL Server 2012 at this point (Jan 2012).  During configuration of TFS 2010, it reports that it cannot find a database, even though 2012 is installed.

Answer (score 2):

TFS2010 with SQL Server 2012 can only work with chek-in check-out project. 
In order to complete TFS Configuration wizard 
   (1) uncheck (Reporting Service) 
   (2) uncheck (SharePoint Service) 
and complete configuration wizard. 
Reports and Bugs and Query will not work for TFS project check - check out can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can install TFS2010 using a SQL2012RTM though. After installation use the wizard for the basic configuration (without the reporting component, see [install/config guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24337)).

Using the Wizard for the Single-Server scenario, which is the recommended version, does not seem to work as it has some issues with RS/AS that have to be solved first.